# Magento 2 admin can not be openend 404 error - Debugging (Behind Reverse Proxy)

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I can not open the admin panel and get a 404.

The `$this->_routerList` does not contain the admin route.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `\Magento\Framework\App\Http::launch`. There is a line

```
    $areaCode = $this->_areaList->getCodeByFrontName($this->_request->getFrontName());
```

which determines the area.

The admin route is only loaded, if the area is detected as adminhtml.

Digging down leads you to `\Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::isHostBackend`

There is a check whether the current URL (unsecure URL or custom_admin_url) matches the current host.

In cases where this does not match (for example if behind a proxy), this might fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but i faced a scenario with this in my  2.4.3

@Alex helped to find out where to look,   and digging a little more  i found out that my path on core_config_data was not set.

web/unsecure/base_url .

In my scenario i am using https .

I   added:

php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="https://myhost.com/"

And with this showed the admin area